# We don't have all devices available..then how to check responsiveness

Tags: css, responsive-design

how  to check whether the site is responsive or not,if We don't have all devices? Is there any perfect tool for that...we fallow responsinator.com or breakpoint of mozilla browser..

Comment: Many responsive designs work with JS detection of viewport width. Try to change the width of your browser window to see some action.

Comment: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-test-responsive-designs-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

Just resize your browser and that will show you how your site looks like on smaller devices. If you want to test your site on specific platforms and browsers you do not have, i'd suggest something like browserstack.com

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read Ethan Marcotte's Responsive Web Design. In this book author explains everything about responsive web development.
[http://www.amazon.com/Responsive-Design-Brief-People-Websites/dp/098444257X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098444257X)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.responsinator.com/

use this link u can check responsive site